# Issue in rendering data as json in ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion

I'm a newbie in ColdFusion and I'm facing one issue while rendering json data to the jquery datatable. Below is the ajaxSource page of my datatable

**getData.cfm**

```html
<cfcontent type="application/x-javascript">

<cfset partyId = 100001 />

<cfstoredproc procedure="proc_get_uploaded_details" datasource="#request.dataSource#">
<cfprocparam value="#partyId#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT">
<cfprocresult name="getUploadDtls">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfset data = [] />

<cfoutput query="getUploadDtls">
<cfif user_session_id eq Session.SessionID>
<cfset deleteLink = "<span class='delete-link link'>Delete</span>" />
<cfelse>
<cfset deleteLink = "">
</cfif>
    <cfset obj = {
        "ID" = id,
        "ORG_NAME" = original_name,
  "GEN_NAME" = generated_name,
  "TYPE" = type,
  "PATH" = path,
  "URL" = "<a href='renderpdf.cfm?path=#path#&name=#original_name#' target='_blank'>Preview</a>",
  "DELETE" = deleteLink
      } />
      <cfset arrayAppend(data, obj) />
</cfoutput>

<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes">
    <cfoutput>
        {"aaData":
        #serializeJSON(data)#
        }
    </cfoutput>
</cfprocessingdirective>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No" showdebugoutput="No">
```

Here is the json result of this page

```
       {"aaData"://
    [{"GEN_NAME":"pdf_60.pdf","PATH":"C:\\NAM\\WebUploads\\100001\\Medical Reports\\pdf_60.pdf","DELETE":"<span class='delete-link link'>Delete</span>","ORG_NAME":"pdf.pdf","ID":33,"TYPE":"Medical Reports","URL":"<a href='renderpdf.cfm?path=C:\\NAM\\WebUploads\\100001\\Medical Reports\\pdf_60.pdf&name=pdf.pdf' target='_blank'>Preview<\/a>"}]
    }
```

In the above result two extra forward slashes are getting appended from some where, just after the `{"aaData":` also one extra backward slash getting appended in the closing of the anchor tag `<\/a>` I have no idea from where this is getting included.

This page is working perfectly in ColdFusion 10, problem is in CF 9 server.

Here is the json result in ColdFusion 10

```
        {"aaData":
    [{"GEN_NAME":"pdf_60.pdf","PATH":"C:\\NAM\\WebUploads\\100001\\Medical Reports\\pdf_60.pdf","DELETE":"<span class='delete-link link'>Delete</span>","ORG_NAME":"pdf.pdf","ID":33,"TYPE":"Medical Reports","URL":"<a href='renderpdf.cfm?path=C:\\NAM\\WebUploads\\100001\\Medical Reports\\pdf_60.pdf&name=pdf.pdf' target='_blank'>Preview</a>"}]
    }
```

No extra slashes here. Why this is happening?

Comment: I'm at a loss. No bugs seem relevant. Maybe you found one. Try eliminating whitespace or carragie returns. Maybe do _{"aaData": #serializejson(data)# }_   ... getting rid of the carraige returns. CF is trying to escape something it seems.

Comment: FYI - I have not hope that will work - I just think if you try some things you might find something useful that's all. :)

Comment: There is a security setting in the ColdFusion administrator to _Prefix serialized JSON with:_. By default it is set to two forward slashes like you are seeing `//`. You can disable that setting but you need to research the security ramifications of doing so. OR you can just remove those first two characters from the returned JSON before you start doing anything with it. [See this reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/ajax_security.html) I DO NOT recommend disabling the setting.

Comment: [Miguel-F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1636917/miguel-f) Yes you are correct, this is because of the security settings in ColdFusion administrator console. Thanks a lot for the information

Answer (score 4):

*Promoted from the comments*

There is a security setting in the ColdFusion administrator to *Prefix serialized JSON with:*. By default it is set to two forward slashes like you are seeing `//`. This helps protect the code from some JavaScript vulnerabilities. You can disable that setting but you need to research the security ramifications of doing so. OR you can just remove those first two characters from the returned JSON before you start doing anything with it. [See this reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/ajax_security.html). I DO NOT recommend disabling the setting.

You can do something like this to remove those initial characters:

```
right(data,stringlen(data)-2)
```

This is just one way to do it. There are others of course.